# How to switch Source control types in TFS 2015 update 3

Tags: git, tfs-2015, tfvc

We currently have TFS 2015 update 3 with 1 production collection and a Teat area Collection. There are 5 Projects under that production area which represent lines of business, The projects were originally created using TFS GIT. There is a request to switch to source control to TFVC. Nobody is using the GIT. So here are my questions:

Can I switch the source control type for each project to TFVC?
Or
Can I add TFVC to each project and “hide” Git?
Or
Can I fix this in an upgrade to TFS 2017 by building the TFS 2017 environment and them migrate the 2015 data to 2017?
Or
Is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

Add TFVC repositories to your team projects and then delete the Git repositories.

You can't selectively disable one type of source control.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply switch the source control type, but you can migrate from Git to TFVC.

Since TFS 2015 update1 we can [use Git and TFVC repos in the same team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/git/team-projects).

So, you can add a TFVC repo to a Git team project, then migrate the existing Git sources to TFVC.

You can migrate all history of main branch from local repo to a new TFVC repo with following steps:

1. Install [git-tf](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) tool at first
2. Add an empty TFVC repo
3. Go to your local Repo folder, and use `git-tf checkin --deep` command to checkin the local repo to a TFVC team project. By default, the checkin command will create a single TFS changeset for the aggregate of all changes made on the current branch in Git since the last checkin to TFS. When used with the **--deep** option, a TFS changeset will be created for each Git commit on the current branch since the last checkin to TFS.

**Reference: [GIT to TFVC](https://fabiostawinski.wordpress.com/2017/03/22/tfvc-to-git-to-tfvc-is-it-possible/)**

Also this similar thread : [Convert Git repository to TFVC version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397169/convert-git-repository-to-tfvc-version-control)

[image]