# Convert Git repository to TFVC version control

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, tfvc

I have a local git repository and i would like to convert it to TFVC version control and then load it to TFS server. Does anyone have an idea how to do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate Git repository to new TFVC repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349494/migrate-git-repository-to-new-tfvc-repository)

Comment: The duplicate doesn't mention the configure command in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To migrate Git repo to TFVC repo, you need to install [git-tf](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) tool at first.

And also make sure you have added a TFVC repo before migration. And assume the TFVC repo name is `projectname`.

After installing git-tf successful, then use below commands to checkin the files and histories in TFS TFVC repo:

```
cd /payh/to/local/git/repo
git tf configure http://tfs-server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection "$\projectname"
git-tf checkin --deep --autosquash
```

Now all the files and histories in your git repo are checkin your TFS TFVC repo.

Comment: Actually, i tried git-tf , i installed it then i added the environment variable but when tried to excute the command i got this error  : "git: 'tf' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        tag"

Comment: try git-tf instead of git tf

Comment: @sila Add the folder to your path (and restart the console) should solve this problem.

Comment: @sila If `git tf` is not recongnized, that means it didn't install correctly. As the **Installing** part of document https://gittf.codeplex.com/ instruct, you should extract the zip file and add the git-tf and java.exe in environment path.

Comment: git-tf is now recognized thanks, i just got another error :  "A server path must be absolute"

Comment: Local branch must be named “master”. If you get "git-tf: 'refs/heads/master' is not a valid ref." error, go to Git repository branches and try to rename local branch to "master".

Answer (score 0):

If you are on TFS 2017 update 1 or higher, you could directly import your [existing Git Repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository) to the TFS Server

If you would like to really migrate your Git repo you could take a look at this thread for details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349494/migrate-git-repository-to-new-tfvc-repository).