# How do I port git changes on TFS?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs, version-control

We have outsourced some work on our ASP.NET MVC website. The outsourcing company copied the source code on `BitBucket` and worked with this version control system.

Now we need to port these changes on a `TFS`-controlled VStudio solution. What can I do?

I've cloned my `git` repository inside VStudio 2019 but I don't what to do next.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use [TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/what-is-tfvc?view=azure-devops) for [GIT as Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/get-started/what-is-repos?view=azure-devops) in TFS? Which version of TFS do you use?

Comment: TFS 2015 and VStudio 2019

Answer (score -1):

1. If you want to import your repo into Team Foundation Version Control, you can try to use git-tf tool. Here you can find the answer: [Convert Git repository to TFVC version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397169/convert-git-repository-to-tfvc-version-control)
2. If you want to import into GIT repo on TFS, you can follow this instruction: [Manually import a repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#manually-import-a-repo). Or update to the latest TFS (now Azure DevOps) version and use the wizard: [Import into a new repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#import-into-a-new-repo)

Comment: Thanks. What I need, is to get changes and create a shelve I can unshelve on my TFS repository.