# Azure DevOps - how can you copy the history of a project from one project collection to another project collection?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

Good Morning and Good Evening Everyone,
Is there a way to migrate or copy all history of a project in one project collection and move to another project collection?

For example:

- I have a project collection called 'A' and 'B'
- Project Collection 'A' has a .Net project that is called SalesApp.
- The SalesApp has changesets that I want to keep and copy to project collection 'B'.
- How do I copy my project plus the changesets into project collection 'B'?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

> Azure DevOps - how can you copy the history of a project from one project collection to another project collection?

I am afraid there is no such out of box way to achieve this. Since TFVC does not support migration between team projects.

You could try to import a GIT repo from other project will store the history info. So using GIT as a bridge is the only workaround here to keep history info. Sorry for any inconvenience for not make it more clearly. GIT here is just a bridge. You need first convert your TFVC repo to GIT.

Then move converted GIT to TFVC. Finally in target project, convert GIT back to TFVC. Just also use git-tfs command line. For your reference: [Convert Git repository to TFVC version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397169/convert-git-repository-to-tfvc-version-control)

Besides, there is a 3rd tool, you can try it with [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility).